# Why do I get the following message when using mv: "mv: setting attribute 'security.selinux' for 'security.selinux': Operation not permitted"

Tags: bash, shell, sh, selinux, mv

I have written the following code to move files into different directories. However, when moving certain files I get the following error message "mv: setting attribute 'security.selinux' for 'security.selinux': Operation not permitted".

I only get this message for "Production" files that I am transferring to another directory on the hard drive. For all other file types, I am transferring them to another hard drive and I do not get the message.

Does anyone know what this error message means? It looks to me like the files are still being moved successfully, but I want to make sure it is not messing up the files.

How can I prevent this message?

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=",", read -r DateTime Type
do
    if [ "$Type" == "Production" ]
    then
        echo "Moving file ${DateTime}_raw.root to 21Nept_disk2/RootFiles"
        mv ../21Nept_disk1/2022May_21Ne_pt/${DateTime}_raw.root RootFiles
    elif [ "$Type" == "Calibration" ] || [ "$Type" == "Pulser" ]
    then
        echo "Moving file ${DateTime}_raw.root to 21Nept_disk1/CalFiles"
        mv ../21Nept_disk1/2022May_21Ne_pt/${DateTime}_raw.root ../21Nept_disk1/CalFiles
    elif [ "$Type" == "Junk" ]
    then
        echo "Moving file ${DateTime}_raw.root to 21Nept_disk1/JunkFiles"
        mv ../21Nept_disk1/2022May_21Ne_pt/${DateTime}_raw.root ../21Nept_disk1/JunkFiles
    elif [ "$Type" == "Test" ] || [ "$Type" == "Investigation" ]
    then
        echo "Moving file ${DateTime}_raw.root to 21Nept_disk1/MiscFiles"
        mv ../21Nept_disk1/2022May_21Ne_pt/${DateTime}_raw.root ../21Nept_disk1/MiscFiles
    elif [ "$Type" == "Carbon" ]
    then
        echo "Moving file ${DateTime}_raw.root to 21Nept_disk1/CarbonFiles"
        mv ../21Nept_disk1/2022May_21Ne_pt/${DateTime}_raw.root ../21Nept_disk1/CarbonFiles
    else
        echo "Error"
    fi
done < RunTypesv1.csv
```

Comment: What filesystem is `21Nept_disk2`? Is it the same filesystem type as `21Nept_disk1`? Does the filesystem support labeling?

Comment: @jordanm No, 21Nept_disk1 is /dev/sda1 and 21Nept_disk 2 is /dev/sdb1

Comment: What are the filesystem types of both? Do both filesystem types support SELinux labeling?

Comment: @jordanm Are sda1 and sdb1 not the file systems? How can I tell if they support SELinux labelling?

Comment: No, those are physical devices. You can use `df -hT` to show filesystem types for those mounted devices. An example would be `xfs` or `ext4`.

Comment: @jordanm They are both ext4